# Proposal to merge tags [commute] and [commuter]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Why is there a [commute](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commute) tag and a [commuter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commuter) tag and should these two be merged?

Answer (score 3):

I've put a proposal in to merge them.

People who are interested (and have >2500 rep) can upvote the merge here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/commuter/synonyms

Comment: I "approved" it, so they're now merged into a single tag. (Also did the thing that replaces the obsoleted tag everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it two different things ?

- Commute : The people who commute to work using a bicycle
- Commuter : The bike type used to do the commute

Comment: I would read a commuter as the person who commutes. Whereas a commute is the journey itself. I think there is sufficient ambiguity as to which tag to use and the commonality of the content to merge the tags.